# Mobile Operating systems and the programming language(s) they are written in

Tags: operating-system

dears.
There is a question in my head I need to ask:
I want one day/night create a mobile Operating system using C programming language.

We know such Operating systems like iOS, Android, Windows phone and so.
when a programmer make a decision to write applications for -X- Operating system (here we assume iOS), he/she has to findout which programming language iOS Operating system is written in.
Well, as it is, the iOS Operating system is written in C/C++
and objective C, with Hybrid (XNU) Kernel type.
Finally he/she starts writing applications for the iOS
Operating system.

-> All I want to know is that, what does this mean when an OS is written in such language and you HAVE TO write softwares using the SAME language that that OS is written in. ?
-> What is the main reason?

Please explain it to me in details.
Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: APIs man. APIs. You're not forced to use the same languages though.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately, SO is not a place where you can ask for a tutorial (_"Please explain it to me in details"_) on a subject that would take anybody years to learn.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programming language C was written to be used to program the UNIX operating system. Just because the UNIX operating system is mostly written in C it doesn't mean you have to use C to program on UNIX.

The language the operating system is written in has nothing to do with what can be ran on the system.

For example, Java can be ran on any system that can support a JVM. In fact, the JVM code is written mostly in C so that it can be ported to almost any platform that can compile C code. This is what makes Java so powerful.

Higher languages such as C and Java are meant to be ran on any platform where they are supported. This is the difference between high level and low level. Low level languages like Assembler can only be ran on a specific processor.

To sum up, the language that the operating system is written in has nothing to do with can be ran on the system. When you are targeting a specific system such as Mac OSX or Windows you can use any high level language like C, C++, Java, Python...

Comment: So if I'm right, you mean we have to make our targeting operating system: 'Support X language', right? And doesn't matter what language it is written in. But there has to be a possibility for that. (Like you said about java and JVM connection).

Comment: @Milad yes that is correct

Comment: Well thank you so much, and I wish you success.